# How to get first 5 characters from string

Tags: php, substring

How to get first 5 characters from string using php

```
$myStr = "HelloWordl";
```

result should be like this

```
$result = "Hello";
```

Comment: Better question would be : How to get first n characters from a string?

Answer (score 679, accepted):

For [single-byte strings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-byte_encoding) (e.g. US-ASCII, ISO 8859 family, etc.) use [`substr`](http://php.net/substr) and for [multi-byte strings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-byte_character_set) (e.g. UTF-8, UTF-16, etc.) use [`mb_substr`](http://php.net/mb_substr):

```
// singlebyte strings
$result = substr($myStr, 0, 5);
// multibyte strings
$result = mb_substr($myStr, 0, 5);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I needed it for: `if(substr($myURL, 0, 4) == "www.")
  $myURL = preg_replace('/www./', '', $myURL, 1);`

Comment: You really only need str_replace('www.','', $url);  Dont have to check if it exists.

Comment: @DougCassidy: what if `$url = "www.subwww.myweirddomainwww.com"`? Without the initial check for `substr($url, 0, 4)`, returned `$url` is ruined!!

Comment: `preg_replace('/^www\./', '', $myURL, 1);` now it needs to start with www

Answer (score 59):

Use [`substr()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php):

```
$result = substr($myStr, 0, 5);
```

Comment: `substr("Häagen-Dazs", 0, 5) == "Häag"` - what am i doing wrong?

Comment: @stereofrog: You’re probably using a multi-byte character encoding like UTF-8. In that case use `mb_substr`.

Answer (score 28):

You can use the [`substr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) function like this:

```
echo substr($myStr, 0, 5);
```

The second argument to `substr` is from what position what you want to start and third arguments is for how many characters you want to return.

Answer (score 26):

An alternative way to get only one character.

```
$str = 'abcdefghij';
echo $str{5};
```

I would particularly not use this, but for the purpose of education. We can use that to answer the question:

```
$newString = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
    $newString .= $str{$i};
}
echo $newString;
```

For anyone using that. Bear in mind curly brace syntax for accessing array elements and string offsets is deprecated from PHP 7.4

More information:
https://wiki.php.net/rfc/deprecate_curly_braces_array_access

Comment: This is the right answer to the wrong question.  Downvoted.

Comment: Because it requires more than copy pasting?

Comment: NOTE: For multi-byte character sets such as UTF-8, must instead use `mb_substr(i, 1)` to get `i`th character.   @RobertPounder - because it doesn't extend to getting more than one character.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve, if you say so; `$string = "Häagen-Dazs";
$stringFirstChars = function($amount, $string) { $i=0;$done=false;$return = '';while($done == false) {$return.=$string{$i};if($amount===$i)$done=true;$i++;}return $return;};

var_dump($stringFirstChars(5, $string));`

(copy paste that into phptester.net or w.e)

Comment: Yes I know. I didn't personally downvote it; I just observed in what way it doesn't answer the question. What you wrote - *that* would be a complete answer: showing a beginner how in php one extends from getting one character to multiple characters. Useful addition to the Q&A - thank you.

Comment: @mickmackusa, in addition to that, since PHP 7.4 curly braces method for accessing array elements has been deprecated

Comment: We are going to need more DVers if we are ever going to get the tally down to -1 where it can be deleted.

Answer (score -3):

You can get your result by simply use [substr()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php):

**Syntax**
*substr(string,start,length)*

Example

```
<?php
$myStr = "HelloWordl";
echo substr($myStr,0,5);
?>
```

Output :

```
 Hello
```

Comment: This VERY late post adds no value and merely bloats the page because everything that it says has already been said (years earlier).  Please do not post an answer unless you have something unique and valuable to add.  Downvoted this answer to discourage useless, late posts.

Comment: @Varin It's ok to post answers 7 years later. Code changes. It just needs to be valuable (not a duplicate) which his wasn't so he got scolded.

Comment: @JustinBreen I wrote that comment 4 years ago. Those 4 extra years of experience in the industry made me see how cringe that comment was, which I forgot about, until now.