# Only use first 6 charcters in submitted field when parsing php

Tags: php, javascript, forms, input

I have an input field that posts to this bit of php and works fine but i'd like users to be able to enter more than 6 characters into the input form and then have the following only use the first 6 characters:

example:
user enters: 1234567890
PHP (or javascript before the post) uses only "123456" and disregards "7890"

Here is the bit of php that's working as long as a user only enters 6 characters:

```
  ?php function getCode() {
 if (isset($_GET["code"])) {
   if ($_GET["code"] == "example1" || $_GET["code"] == "example1") {
    echo '<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=http://www.example.com">';
    } else if ($_GET["code"] == "example2" || $_GET["code"] == "example2") {
    echo '<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=http://www.example2.com">';
    } else if ($_GET["code"] != "example1" || $_GET["code"] != "example2") {
   //Looks like your lot number didn't work.
    $message =  '<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=http://www.example.com/noworky">';

   };
    return $message;
 };
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what's being asked, but to get the first six characters of a string use `substr($string, 0, 6)`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to get first 5 characters from string using php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3787540/how-to-get-first-5-characters-from-string-using-php)

Comment: @Gordon: Not exactly. The OP doesn't know that the solution is what the OP of the other thread was asking about.

Comment: @Tomalak that is completely irrelevant

Comment: @Gordon I disagree, but each to their own I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Use [the `substr` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) to chop the input `$_GET['code']` down to 6 characters, then compare that.

Why do you have all these redundantly duplicated conditions? And why the `;` after the `}`s? I really recommend getting yourself a good book. Programming by guessing does not work [well].

Comment: I know I don't know, which is why I'm on here trying to learn, I appreciate your advice but "I really recommend getting yourself a good book. Programming by guessing does not work [well]." doesn't work well either. I inherited the code this way so I'd like to clean it up if it's not properly formatted. Thanks, -newb

Comment: @smudge I know "read a book" is template advice, and that your first instinct is to shun it... but, honestly, it should be done. You'll understand why when you have.

Answer (score 0):

```
$_GET["code"] = substr($_GET["code"],0,6);
```