# Get first 5 hexadecimal character and convert to decimal php

Tags: php, hex, decimal

I have a 128 character hex string.

I need to get the first 5 characters and then convert them to a decimal, which I will do with hexdec()

How can I get the first 5 characters?

Comment: http://php.net/substr — `$first_five = substr($string, 0, 5);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
$decvalue = hexdec(substr($the_string, 0, 5));
```

Answer (score 0):

1)use substr to get 5 digits

`$value = substr($yourstring, 0, 5);`

[look into exammple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3787540/how-to-get-first-5-characters-from-string-using-php)

2)Then convert them to decimal