# How to get 8 first and last from php var (utf-8)?

Tags: php, utf-8

How to get 8 first and last from php var (utf-8) ?

I tried this code but not show 8 first and last.

```
<?PHP
$file_name= "Μια φορά κι έναν καιρό";

$first_8_char_file_name_display = mb_substr($file_name, 0, 8, "utf-8");
$last_8_char_file_name_display = mb_substr($file_name ,-8, "utf-8");

echo $first_8_char_file_name_display;
echo "<BR>";
echo $last_8_char_file_name_display;
?>
```

How can i do that ?

Comment: try using `mb_substr` instead of `substr` - it is multi-byte safe.

Comment: I've updated my answer.. take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do this:

```
$file_name= "Μια φορά κι έναν καιρό";
$from = strlen($file_name)/2-6;
$first_8_char_file_name_display = mb_substr($file_name, 0, 8,"utf-8");
$last_8_char_file_name_display = mb_substr($file_name, $from, 8,"utf-8");

echo $from;
echo "<br/>";
echo $first_8_char_file_name_display;
echo "<br/>";
echo $last_8_char_file_name_display;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `mb_substr` instead, as it supports multi-byte strings:

```
$first_8_char_file_name_display = mbsubstr($file_name, 0, 8);
$last_8_char_file_name_display = mbsubstr($file_name, -8);
```

For [single-byte strings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-byte_encoding) (e.g. US-ASCII, ISO 8859 family, etc.) use [`substr`](http://php.net/substr).

For [multi-byte strings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-byte_character_set) (e.g. UTF-8, UTF-16, etc.) use [`mb_substr`](http://php.net/mb_substr)

*Referenced from [How to get first 5 characters from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3787540/how-to-get-first-5-characters-from-string).*

Hope this helps, thanks!