# remove char '"' in string and create array in php

Tags: php

I have a this string: `"["ST09390.2","ST62801.4"]"` and I would like to create a array with this result, so I need a remove a first char " and last char ".

I try a `trim($mndcheckout['ids'], """)` but this is no solution.

Comment: Is it meant to be JSON? In which case just use [json_decode](http://php.net/json_decode). Perhaps provide a replication case of what your issue is and what you're trying to get to.

Comment: I want to create a array with this result.

Comment: One of these examples https://3v4l.org/nLvHY ?

Answer (score 1):

> I try a trim($mndcheckout['ids'], """) but this is no solution.

Yout have to escape the " as a \"

> "["ST09390.2","ST62801.4"]"

Strange quoted .. try this:

```
$j = <<<STRING
"["ST09390.2","ST62801.4"]"
STRING;
$j = trim($j, "\"");

$a = json_decode($j);

print_r($a);
/*
Array
(
    [0] => ST09390.2
    [1] => ST62801.4
)
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly str_replace function to remove unwanted stuff, If you aware about input string. You can refer below code for your expected result.

```
$str = '"["ST09390.2","ST62801.4"]"';
$str = str_replace('["','',$str);
$str = str_replace(']"','',$str);

$arr = explode(',', $str);
print_r($arr);
```

This is tested code, I hope this will resolve your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that the string is always in this format then you can use:

```
json_decode(substr($string, 1, -1),TRUE);
```

Have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php ,
http://php.net/substr .
As is said in the answer to this question, [How to get first 5 characters from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3787540/how-to-get-first-5-characters-from-string), for multi-byte strings (e.g. UTF-8, UTF-16, etc.) use mb_substr instead of substr.